# Can Resharper change var to explicit types?

Tags: resharper

Is it possible to make Resharper's tool "Cleanup code" (in Visual Studio) to change all `var` to explicit types?

Example: I'd like this:

```
var person = new Person();
```

to be changed to this:

```
Person person = new Person();
```

**Edit after suggested solutions:**

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it doesn't work for me:

[image: image showing how the suggested solution doesn't work]

Comment: As an aside, why don't you want implicit-typing?

Answer (score 9):

You can set this up in the (Resharper) options under Code Cleanup.
Just create a new profile/modify an existing one and then navigate to C#->Use 'var' in declaration.
Set the "Replace direction" to "Can (change) 'var' to type usage" and "Local variable declaration style" to "Always use explicit type"

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the "Code cleanup" tool, under "Use 'var' in declaration" set the "Replace direction" to "Can 'var' to type usage".

[image: Creating Custom Profiles]

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: you can also stop resharper from defaulting to var when doing "introduce variable".

**These settings are under Code Editing --> C# --> Code Style**

[image]